# jq: how to perform unmerge / multi-level object subtraction i.e. given X and Y, find Z such that X * Z = Y

Tags: json, merge, jq, inverse

Using `jq` we can easily merge two multi-level objects X and Y using `*`:

```
X='{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 5,
    "c": {
      "a": 3
    }
  }' Y='{
    "d": 2,
    "a": 3,
    "c": {
      "x": 10,
      "y": 11
    }
  }' && Z=`echo "[$X,$Y]"|jq '.[0] * .[1]'` && echo "Z='$Z'"
```

gives us:

```
Z='{
  "a": 3,
  "b": 5,
  "c": {
    "a": 3,
    "x": 10,
    "y": 11
  },
  "d": 2
}'
```

But in my case, I'm starting with X and Z and want to calculate Y (such that X * Y = Z). If we only have objects with scalar properties, then `jq X + Y` equals `Z`, and we can also calculate `Y` as `jq Z - X`. However, this fails if X or Y contain properties with object values such as in the above example:

```
X='{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 5,
    "c": {
      "a": 3
    }
  }' Z='{
  "a": 3,
  "b": 5,
  "c": {
    "a": 3,
    "x": 10,
    "y": 11
  },
  "d": 2
}' && echo "[$X,$Z]" | jq '.[1] - .[0]'
```

throws an error `jq: error (at <stdin>:16): object ({"a":3,"b":...) and object ({"a":1,"b":...) cannot be subtracted`

Is there an elegant solution to this problem with jq?

UPDATE: I've accepted the answer that I found easier to read / maintain and with superior performance. In addition, I found a wrinkle in my need which was that if X contained a key K that was not present in Z, I needed the output (Y) to nullify it by containing the key K with a value of null.

The best way I could come up with to do this was to pre-process Z to add the missing keys using the below:

```
def add_null($y):
    reduce (to_entries[] | [ .key, .value ] ) as [ $k, $v ] (
       $y;
       if $y | has($k) | not then
          .[$k] = null
       elif $v | type == "object" then
          .[$k] = ($v | add_null($y[$k]))
       else
          .[$k] = $v
       end
    );
```

so we end up with:

```
def add_null(...);

def remove(...);

. as [ $X, $Z ] | ($X | add_null($Z)) | remove($X)
```

Any better suggestions to this variation are still appreciated!

Comment: Given just X and Z, there are many solutions to Y such that X * Y = Z, not just the one from your sample.

Comment: @pmf, There is a minimal one, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def remove($o2):
   reduce ( to_entries[] | [ .key, .value ] ) as [ $k, $v1 ] (
      {};
      if $o2 | has($k) | not then
         # Keep existing value if $o2 doesn't have the key.
         .[$k] = $v1
      else
         $o2[$k] as $v2 |
         if $v1 | type == "object" then
            # We're comparing objects.
            ( $v1 | remove($o2[$k]) ) as $v_diff |
            if $v_diff | length == 0 then
               # Discard identical values.
               .
            else
               # Keep the differences of the values.
               .[$k] = $v_diff
            end
         else
            # We're comparing non-objects.
            if $v1 == $v2 then
               # Discard identical values.
               .
            else
               # Keep existing value if different.
               .[$k] = $v1
            end
         end
      end
   );

. as [ $Z, $X ] | $Z | remove($X)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ySwGC2FClo) on jqplay

or

```
def sub($v2):
   (       type ) as $t1 |
   ( $v2 | type ) as $t2 |
   if $t1 == $t2 then
      if $t1 == "object" then
         with_entries(
            .key as $k |
            .value = (
               .value |
               if $v2 | has($k) then sub( $v2[$k] ) else . end
            )
         ) |
         select( length != 0 )
      else
         select( . != $v2 )
      end
   else
      .
   end;

. as [ $Z, $X ] | $Z | sub($X)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/p8QNzPMv2_) on jqplay

Comment: Thanks. Your X and Z are flipped from what I intended, but that is probably because when I initially posted the subtraction formula, I had `.[0]` and `.[1]` reversed (it's fixed/changed now). AFAICT this (nicely commented, btw) yields the same result as the answer I've accepted, but feel free to lmk if that's not the case or there are other reasons why this one might be better/different

Comment: @mwag, If you want to provide the operands "backwards", you just need to adjust the last line. /// pmf's solutions works. It even handles identical objects like mine does. But I'm very concerned about the performance of array subtraction, and the other uses it repeatedly. It might not be an issue, but it's a huge red flag to me.

Comment: I see. I will test on some real data with a couple hundred keys and update in a few days...

Comment: I ran some performance tests myself: the "*elegance*" of my solution cost roughly five times more than any of these solutions; tested with an X of around 300K and a minimal Y.

Comment: @ikegami is there a difference between your two solutions in terms of output or performance (or other)? It seems not, just want to make sure I'm reading correctly

Comment: No idea. They both scale as best as possible (O(N+M)), but I haven't measured their individual performance. The difference is that I I was attempting to handle any data type in the latter. I wasn't sure what to put in `elif $t1 == "array"`, though, so I didn't. So the only real difference is that the second is shorter, but possibly less clear.

Comment: One difference is that the second one also [works](https://jqplay.org/s/cVSAGj_J2w) if X, Y and Z are arrays, the first one [doesn't](https://jqplay.org/s/HDRkj-R65N) (although it should when looking at the code).

Comment: @pmf, For some definition of works. If any part of the array (including any part of objects in the array) is different, it will be considered entirely different. This differs from the definition of differences for objects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is elegant, but it works for your sample data

```sh
echo "[$X,$Z]" | jq '
  . as [$x,$z]
  | map([paths(scalars)])
  | .[0] |= map(select(. as $p | [$x, $z | getpath($p)] | .[1] == .[0]))
  | reduce (.[1] - .[0])[] as $p (null; setpath($p; $z | getpath($p)))  
'
```

```json
{
  "a": 3,
  "c": {
    "x": 10,
    "y": 11
  },
  "d": 2
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Y5rEaeFWaU)